# Trying establish Kafka with 2 way SSL but getting an error

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to establish 2 way TLS authentication with Kafka (version 2.4.0).

My server.properties configuration:

```
listeners=SSL://kafka1:9092
advertised.listeners=SSL://<public_ip>:9092
ssl.keystore.location=path/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=pass
ssl.truststore.location=path/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=pass
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
```

client.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka1:9092
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.keystore.location=path/client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=pass
ssl.truststore.location = path/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=pass
```

kafkaServer and zooKeeper are on.
But when I try to create topic:

`kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092 --create --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic sometopic --command-config config/client.properties`

get an error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No name matching kafka1 found
```

My certificate connected to kafka1 name, and there is mapping of kafka1 to local_ip.
Have you seen such an error before?

Comment: This looks like this is run in a docker-compose ensemble? You'd need to also advertise the `kafka1` listener, and you need to run the `kafka-topics.sh` in one of the containers in order for it to find the `kafka1` service.

Comment: I am not using docker. Can you please explain what exetcly i need need to advertise as a listener? And what exectly that container you mentioned? Thank you for your help.